# How to add Recurring Subscription, Installment to payment gateway in Ubercart

Tags: 7, ubercart, payment-gateways

I am using ubercart-7.x-3.9, Drupal 7.43, ClickandPledge(Payment Gateway found at: https://github.com/ClickandPledge/uc_clickandpledge). My Payment Gateway is integrated with Credit Card type for now(using uc_payment, uc_credit dependencies). 
Can someone help me with a way in integrating the functionality. I need a way to display and post my function in checkout on my payment gateway selection.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) This is a Q+A site for narrowly scoped, specific questions, building an entire feature or asking for general help isn't something the format here can support. If you have more specific questions as you continue your development, please ask those separately. Thanks